# patch: run in non-interactive mode

Tags: linux, unix, patch

I would like to automatically test of a set of patches still cleanly applies to an (updated) code base. To this end, I intended to run

```
patch -p 1 < path/to/patch0.patch
```

for all patches `patch*.patch`, check the return code of this command, and store that somewhere. Unfortunately, `patch` appears to work interactively in some cases. A typical output requiring interaction would be

```
can't find file to patch at input line 44
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: foo/docs/faq.html
|===================================================================
|--- foo.orig/docs/faq.html
|+++ foo/docs/faq.html
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

Is there a way to run `patch` non-interactively? (Perhaps `patch` isn't the right tool for the task here.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `-f` (`--force`) option:

```bash
echo a > a
echo b > b
diff -Nu a b > p
rm a b
patch -p 1 < p
```

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- a  2016-05-11 16:16:24.115481324 +0700
|+++ b  2016-05-11 16:16:24.115481324 +0700
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

(asks for input). However,

```
patch -f -p 1 < p
```

```
can't find file to patch at input line 3
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- a  2016-05-11 16:16:24.115481324 +0700
|+++ b  2016-05-11 16:16:24.115481324 +0700
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

exits with exit status (`$?`) 1:

```
echo $?
1
```